# UITableViewCell only displays accessory after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I have a TableView with custom cells that I make from fetching data from a server. I have a variable 'selectedIndex' which I use to keep track and add a checkmark accessory to my cell. Weirdly, it only works after I scroll the selected cell (cell with indexPath.row is equal to  off the screen and back. Here is the code in my willDisplayCell method:

```
if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
    if let accessory = cell.viewWithTag(528) as? UITableViewCell {
        accessory.frame = (cell.checkmarkView.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 7))
        accessory.accessoryType = .checkmark
        accessory.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        accessory.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        accessory.tag = 528
        accessory.isHidden = false
        print("accessory not nil")
     } else {
        let accessory = UITableViewCell()
        accessory.frame = (cell.checkmarkView.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 7))
        accessory.accessoryType = .checkmark
        accessory.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        accessory.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        accessory.tag = 528
        accessory.isHidden = false
        cell.addSubview(accessory) 
        print("accessory nil")        
     }
 } else {
     let accessory = cell.viewWithTag(528)
     accessory?.isHidden = true
 }
```

For example, when the selected index is 0, the checkmark is not displayed at first view, and the logs print ("accessory nil"). When I scroll the cell at index 0 off-screen, and scroll to it again, the checkmark is now displayed and the logs print ("accessory not nil"). For more information, tapping on a cell works just as expected.

Edit:

1. I know I'm adding another TableViewCell to my cell! I'm only doing that because I need my checkmark accessory to be in a different position (left-aligned, top-aligned) than the default one (right-aligned, vertically centered). So what I did was add a view in my XIB that is in the desired position (right-aligned, top-aligned) and and aligned my programatically-made cell to it. If you could show me another approach it would be appreciated.
2. Removed cell.addSubview from the first if. Still behaves the same.

Thanks!

Comment: You are adding over and over again a `UITableViewCell` in your `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Oh boy! Ready about `UITableView` and `UITableViewController`. Especially about reuse of cells. There is so much wrong in your code.

Comment: Why are using tags?

Comment: Hello! @ReinierMelian Please see my update.

Comment: @mugiwara528 if you are using a custom xib, why you are adding inside another cell? use your xib as your primary cell registering as reuse cell in your tableView

Comment: @ReinierMelian I did that. Sorry for the incomplete information in the question. As I said in the edited version, I need a checkmark accessory that is in a different position than the default one, so my approach to that is by making and adding another cell programatically and aligning it to a view in my XIB.

Comment: @mag_zbc I am using tags to find if I have already previously added a view in my cell. Basically, I search for a view with a tag '528' , if it exists, I do not add a view (another cell), else, I add a view.

Comment: @mugiwara528 check my updated answer and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `UITableViewCell` into your **dequeued original cell**, this is unnecessary, you need implement this logic in your `cellForRowAt` **datasource** method,

## updated

If you need a custom position for your accessory view use `cell.layoutMargins` check my updated code

**try this instead**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass
    
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
              cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        //if you need a custom position for your accessory view
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 100)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your updated answer. However, the top and bottom parameters in UIEdgeInsertMake does not seem to be working. I want to position my checkmark in the top right corner.

Comment: I will check @mugiwara528

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` will optimize your cells by reusing them. So in your case it seems better to use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath)` instead of calling the Cell's constructor yourself or find the cell back by looking for it's tag.

Besides that the part which determines the state of the cell should be in the `UITableView`'s `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` function instead of the willDisplayCell. This might solve your problem and prevents issues with reusing cells.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. To your first point, I did use tableView.dequeueReusableCell in my cellForRow method.
To the second point, I moved the code I posted to the cellForRow method, but the issue still occurs.